# How to use getPurchases() - Android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, sharedpreferences, in-app-billing

I have successfully implemented In-App-Billing into my app. The IAP is working successfully and I have tested it to make sure its working. 


When a user clicks on a button, they have to make an IAP to proceed. However, everytime a user clicks on the button it starts the IAP, even though they have already made the IAP. I want my IAP to be non-consumable obviously. Currently, I'm storing the IAP in `SharedPreferences`, but if the user reinstalls the app, they lose their IAP. 


So how can I use `getPurchases()` or `restoreTransactions()` on my `onCreate` or `onClick` method to check whether the user has purchases a specific item? I have searched all over the Internet and read through so many samples and it doesn't seem to work, perhaps I am misunderstanding though.


If you need me to post any code, please ask and I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library:

```
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3
```

How to use?

Use this in your gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
}
```

Manifest permission for in-app billing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

How to use library method:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {
  BillingProcessor bp;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "YOUR LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE", this);
    bp.initialize();
    // or bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, "YOUR LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE", this);
    // See below on why this is a useful alternative
  }

  // IBillingHandler implementation

  @Override
  public void onBillingInitialized() {
    /*
    * Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase 
    */
  }

  @Override
  public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    /*
    * Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
    */
  }

  @Override
  public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
    /*
    * Called when some error occurred. See Constants class for more details
    * 
    * Note - this includes handling the case where the user canceled the buy dialog:
    * errorCode = Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED
    */
  }

  @Override
  public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
    /*
    * Called when purchase history was restored and the list of all owned PRODUCT ID's 
    * was loaded from Google Play
    */
  }
}
```

Note: onPurchaseHistoryRestored called only first time when you initialize BillingProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Their are lot of ways to check onPurchaseHistoryRestored() but its my opinion. And I have solved it by using..
 you can check through transection detail using this code.

```
@Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        /*
         * Called when purchase history was restored and the list of all owned PRODUCT ID's
         * was loaded from Google Play
         */

        // Check whether 'premium_id' has previously been purchased:
        TransactionDetails premiumTransactionDetails = bp.getPurchaseTransactionDetails("premium_id");

        if (premiumTransactionDetails == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseHistoryRestored(): Havn't bought premium yet.");
            purchasePremiumButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseHistoryRestored(): Already purchases premium.");

            purchasePremiumButton.setText(getString(R.string.you_have_premium));
            purchasePremiumButton.setEnabled(false);
            statusTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

And the second is to put the check on "product id".check below code.

```
if(bp.isPurchased(REMOVE_ID_SKU)){
if (bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()) {
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.subs_updated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_purchases, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```